# WPF Accessing Items inside Listbox which has a UserControl as ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, listbox, user-controls, datatemplate

- I have Window that has a ListBox
- ListBox(MyListBox) has a DataTable for its DataContext
- ListBox's ItemSource is : {Binding}
- Listbox has a UserControl(MyUserControl) as DataTemplate
- UserControl has RadioButtons and TextBoxes (At first They're filled with values from DataTable and then user can change them)
- Window has one Submit Button

What I want to do is, when user clicks the submit button

- For each ListBox Item, get the values form UserControl's TextBoxes and RadioButtons.

I was using that method for this job :

```
foreach(var element in MyListBox.Items)
{ 
  var border = MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(element)as FrameworkElement;
  MyUserControl currentControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myBorder,0) as Border,0)as ContentPresenter,0)as MyUserControl;
  //And use currentControl
}
```

I realised nothing when using 3-5 items in Listbox. But when I used much more items, I saw that "var border" gets "null" after some elements looped in foreach function.

I found the reason here :
[ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) return null after 20 items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675926/listview-itemcontainergenerator-containerfromitemitem-return-null-after-20-item)

So what can I do now? I want to access all items and get their values sitting on user controls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use objects who implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bind an `ObservableCollection` of it to the `ItemSource`
And then you can get all the list of items.

Here some quick links from MSDN to get more informations
[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)
[Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)

You should google for some tutorials about this.

Answer (score 0):

Zied's post is a solution for this problem. But I did the following for my project:

- I realised that there's no need to use UserControl as DataTemplate in my project. So I removed ListBox's DataTemplate.
- I removed `MyListBox.DataContext = myDataTable` and used this:

  > ```
  > foreach(DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
  > {
  >  MyUserControl muc = new MyUserControl(dr);
  >  myListBox.Items.Add(muc);
  > }
  > ```
- I took DataRow in my UserControl's constructor and did what I want.
- And at last I could access my UserControls in ListBox by using :

  > ```
  > foreach(MyUserControl muc in
  > myListBox) 
  > { 
  > //do what you want 
  > }
  > ```

Easy huh? :)